# Find nodes inside area (like forest) with OverpassAPI

Tags: overpass-api

I'm still in the processing of learning how to use the OverpassAPI QL syntax in regards to areas.

With the following query I get the forrest areas:

```
[out:json]
[bbox:{{bbox}}];

( 
  way["landuse"="forest"];
  relation["landuse"="forest"];  
  way["natural"="wood"];
  relation["natural"="wood"];
);

out geom;
```

With this query I get the nodes I'm looking for inside the area queried before:

```
[out:json]
[bbox:{{bbox}}];

node[natural=spring];
out;
```

When I combine those to I don't get any output (in Overpass-Turbo):

```
[out:json]
[bbox:{{bbox}}];

( 
  way["landuse"="forest"];
  relation["landuse"="forest"];  
  way["natural"="wood"];
  relation["natural"="wood"];
);
map_to_area;
node(area)[natural=spring];

out;
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not yet available as of release 0.7.55. In case there's no corresponding area available on the Overpass server, this kind of query is simply not feasible.

See https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/77 for details.

Comment: A bit more background Infos: https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/talk/2020-April/084535.html